# Неравномерное распределение текста при разбиении на колонки

Tags: css, css3

Можно ли при разбиении текста на колонки (`column-count`) управлять равномерностью распределения текста по высоте? В частности, нужно чтобы текст не равномерно распределился по двум колонкам (изменив высоту блока), а при заданной высоте блока полностью заполнил одну колонку, и во вторую поместил текста столько, сколько останется.

```
.parent {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.columns {
  height: 100%;
  column-count: 2;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

<div class="parent">
  <div class="columns">При планировании нагрузки мы исходили из того, что одни и те же по величине тренировочные воздействия не приводят к функциональным сдвигам, так как организм адаптируется к нагрузкам. Поэтому, занятия строились с учетом трех режимов нагрузки. Планирование учебных занятий заключалось в постепенном наращивании физической нагрузки. При обосновании планирования нагрузки мы исходили из принципа постепенного увеличения нагрузки. В ее основу положен принцип волнообразного увеличения. Наиболее эффективной формой построения учебных занятий всегда считалась комплексная форма, предусматривающая одновременное решение целого ряда задач и использование нагрузок различной преимущественной направленности.</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/photosho/pen/gOdROmm

Comment: `column-fill: auto;`

Comment: @UModeL, спасибо, то, что нужно.